# Does signing a DLL invalidate a PDB file?

Tags: windbg, debug-symbols, pdb-files

Analyzing a crash dump, WinDbg says my symbols (PDB file) does not match the module. The symbols are the ones generated when the DLL was compiled. The only thing that I can imagine would cause a mismatch is that the DLL was signed.

I'm using `!chksym` to validate symbols:

```
!chksym libcef.dll D:\sym\libcef.dll.pdb

libcef.dll
    Timestamp: 5BB3D477
  SizeOfImage: 626D000
          pdb: F:\src\out\libcef.dll.pdb
      pdb sig: B0065D83-113F-63BE-53BC-AEF07EC816B4
          age: 1

libcef.dll.pdb
      pdb sig: 9BA88A40-D168-44F2-44C1-DD2D73A38B38
          age: 1

sig MISMATCH: libcef.dll.pdb and libcef.dll
```

Comment: With Signing you mean Authenticode signing? I am not aware that this changes the debug header. It more looks like you did recompile the dll from the same sources. You can force a load with .reload -f -i libcef.dll if you symbol path contains the directory where your new pdb is located. Use .sympath+ F:\src\out to add it. Then debugging should be a non issue.

Comment: @AloisKraus Yes, authenticode signing. Force reload seems to work fine. I'm more concern if I may be debugging wrong stuff because of symbol mismatch. Do you how can I look at the debug header?

Comment: I notice your pdb has a .dll appended to it  afaik vc creates pdb with the .dll stripped  ie it creates a libcef.pdb instead of libcef.dll.pdb  do you have a -Fxyz switch passed on that provides a different name for pdb in your projects ?  no signing afaik doesn't change anything inside your binary (imagine ms embedding an oops backdoor if it does that cant it ? )  use dumpbin /headers to check the path embedded inside binary

Answer (score 6):

Code signing an executable or DLL does not affect the debug header of the executable. Thus, it will still match the PDB.

```
...\SigningPdb\bin\Release>symchk signed.exe /s .

SYMCHK: FAILED files = 0
SYMCHK: PASSED + IGNORED files = 1

...\SigningPdb\bin\Release>symchk unsigned.exe /s .

SYMCHK: FAILED files = 0
SYMCHK: PASSED + IGNORED files = 1
```

And

```
...\SigningPdb\bin\Release>ChkMatch.exe -c signed.exe SigningPdb.pdb
ChkMatch - version 1.0
Copyright (C) 2004 Oleg Starodumov
http://www.debuginfo.com/


Executable: signed.exe
Debug info file: SigningPdb.pdb

Executable:
TimeDateStamp: bc78c18e
Debug info: 2 ( CodeView )
TimeStamp: a7b373e5  Characteristics: 0  MajorVer: 0  MinorVer: 0
Size: 97  RVA: 000026a0  FileOffset: 000008a0
CodeView format: RSDS
Signature: {b8ed520c-cdfc-486b-8e1a-7c0752a2a41f}  Age: 1
PdbFile: ...\Release\SigningPdb.pdb
Debug info: 16 ( Unknown )
TimeStamp: 00000000  Characteristics: 0  MajorVer: 0  MinorVer: 0
Size: 0  RVA: 00000000  FileOffset: 00000000

Debug information file:
Format: PDB 7.00
Signature: {b8ed520c-cdfc-486b-8e1a-7c0752a2a41f}  Age: 1

Result: Matched
```

The timestamp is in the COFF header. That header is only 24 bytes in size and will not change during code signing.

Most changes will happen in a new section for certificates. This section, however, will also be ignored during code signing. Otherwise, a second signature would destroy the first signature. (BTW: this section has been used to transport malicious code inside a signed executable)

[image: Stud_PE]

Of course, the "usual" checksums, which do not consider the EXE/DLL file structure, will report a different checksum.

[image: Checksums of executables]

What may have happened to your DLL or EXE?

- you have accidentally rebuilt it, so the time stamp of your DLL does not match the PDB any more
- you are using aspect oriented programming (AOP) in .NET and there is some code weaving happening after a rebuild. These tools might not be able to rebuild the PDB after weaving, so the PDB mismatch is already there before the DLL is code signed.